# Update Xcode project to iOS 4.1

Tags: ios4, upgrade, ios3.0

I started a project under iOS 3.1 and I stopped developing for a while. Now I installed the new SDK with iOS 4.1. If I wanna build now, there is a error message which says "There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.1', which actually make sense.

So how can I "upgrade" my project to iOS 4.1?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project settings search for base SDK and set this to 4.1. You might set the deployment target to 3.x on the targets' info page (that is if you want to target 3.x, of course).